# Third party payment gateway in a ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, payment-gateway, phonegap

I've read the Apple Store Review Guidelines and it doesnt seem to be clear for our use case.

We're developing a cross platform app with phonegap in which the user can buy or get for free some courses (which will be available to the same user on android and browser). What they get is content that a teacher using a separate web app has built (lessons and activities) that the user (student) can review at any time, any amount of times.

Is no clear whether using a third party payment gateway (that opens InAppBrowser) goes against apple store guide. Googling only makes things more confusing. It's certain it's ok for physical products, you can use that payment system.

Also because apple only allows discrete prices for the products, we had to change how a teacher sets the price, we made an incomplete list of the prices available.

We are in the process of implementing the third party payment gateway for the students that'd like to use the browser version.

How should I proceed about this? Should we use the same in all platforms, or use InAppBilling for android an InAppPurchase for ios?

Comment: The rules from Apple are pretty clear. If the content is delivered in the app (which it sounds like it is) then you must use in app purchase. It doesn’t matter if the content they have purchased can also be accessed outside the app. You can also allow the user to purchase content outside the app and make that content available to them inside the app, but you cannot make that external purchase method available from within the app in any way (this includes opening a web page from your app)

Comment: Would you mind pointing me where in the guidelines this is said?

Comment: [Section 3.1.1 first bullet point](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase). The Netflix app is a good example. If you have a Netflix subscription you can log in and use it but the only way to subscribe to Netflix *in the app* is via IAP